# Spark transformation (map) is not called even after calling the action (count)

Tags: apache-spark

I have a map function defined on the DataFrame and when I invoke the action (count() in this case) I am not seeing the function calls invoked inside the map function getting called for each row.

Here is the code I have

```
def copyFilesToArchive(recordDF:DataFrame,s3Util:S3Client):Unit ={
    if(s3Util !=null) {
      // Copy all the Object to new Path
      logger.info(".copyFilesToArchive() : Before Copying the Files to Archive and no.of RDD Partitions ={}",recordDF.rdd.partitions.length);
      recordDF.rdd.map(row => {
        var key = row.getAs("object_key")
        var bucketName = row.getAs("bucket_name")
        var targetBucketName = row.getAs("target_bucket_name")
        var targetKey = "archive/" + "/" + key
        var copyObjectRequest = new CopyObjectRequest(bucketName, key, targetBucketName,targetKey )
        logger.info(".copyFilesToArchive() : Copying the File from ["+key+"] to ["+targetKey+"]");
        s3Util.getS3Client.copyObject(copyObjectRequest)
      })
      logger.info(".copyFilesToArchive() : Copying the Files to Archive Folder. No.of Files to Copy ={}",recordDF.count());
    }
    else{
      logger.info(".copyFilesToArchive() : Skipping Moving the Files as S3 Util is null");
    }
  }
```

And when I run my unit tests I am not seeing the logging statement of copying the files.

INFO  ArchiveProcessor - .copyFilesToArchive() : Before Copying the Files to Archive and no.of RDD Partitions =200
INFO  ArchiveProcessor - .copyFilesToArchive() : Copying the Files to Archive Folder. No.of Files to Copy =3000000

when I use collect() how ever i get OOM Error.

```
if I use collect() then i can see the logging output.

recordDF.collect().map(row => {
 ...
})
```

Thanks
Sateesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spark dataframes are immutable, if you do any transformation it will not change the original dataframe variable.

You are calling action method count() on recordDF but not on transformed version of recordDF i.e `recordDF.rdd.map(//operations)`. Since you are not calling any action method that particular code block is not getting executed.

Since collect() is an action method, `recordDF.collect().map(..)`--> this is working for you. Collect method will bring all the records to driver, if memory is not enough (default is 1 GB) you will get OOM error.

You can use foreach or foreachPartition functions on dataframe -->`recordDF.foreach(row ==> // transformation logic goes here)` or call action on the `recordDF.map.rdd(row=> //...)`

```
val outRDD = recordDF.map.rdd(row=> //...)
logger.info("--<your message>--", outRDD.count)
```